# Citing a lecture

Tags: citations, citation-style

I recently attended a talk and the talk was recorded and posted to YouTube, and the slides are available on the author's webpage. I would like to cite this talk in some work I am doing, and there are no other references for this material. How should I cite this?

This is the talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meOQXoN0QRc

And these are the slides https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/Anomaly.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Cite a Lecture?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/188512/how-do-i-cite-a-lecture)

Comment: related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10411/how-to-cite-lecture-notes-and-should-i-even-do-this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absent a specific rule, I would cite the video using "Freed, Dan" as your author, "Dan Freed | Feb. 7, 2023 | What is an anomaly?" as the article name (because that's how it's labeled, even though it duplicates other information), *Mathematical Picture Language* as the publication/journal, and Youtube.com as the publisher. Note the date of the presentation as if it were the publication date (which it looks like it actually was). List the link and the "retrieved on" date. Do this all according to the the citation system (MLA, APA, etc) that you are using. For the slides, I'd probably treat U Texas as the publisher.

In any case, the important thing is to give credit *and* make it possible for someone else to find it. The technicalities for web materials are not fixed like they are for books, so just try to be as consistent as possible.

Answer (score 10):

You can cite is pretty much as you do here along with author and title, but add a date at which you accessed them as you should for any internet (or other volatile) reference. Alternately cite a reference at the wayback machine.

For a talk, give the date and venue of the presentation for things you visit "live".

Comment: I would suggest that even if you don't cite using a Wayback Machine link, that you still [request that the page is saved](https://web.archive.org/save/). That way there is at least some record of the page that exists as you viewed it.

Answer (score 3):

Buffy is correct, especially about using the Wayback Machine for the pdf slides.

In LaTeX with biblatex, your entries would be:

```
@online{freed_youtube,
    title = {What is an anomaly?},
    date = {2023-02-07},
    author = {Freed, Dan},
    url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meOQXoN0QRc},
    urldate = {2023-02-09},
    organization = {The Mathematical Picture Language Project}
}

@online{freed_slides,
    title = {What is an anomaly?},
    date = {2023-02-07},
    author = {Freed, Dan},
    url = {https://web.archive.org/web/20230209103515/https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/Anomaly.pdf},
    urldate = {2023-02-09}
}
```

Comment: Would it be good to add `organization = {University of Texas at Austin}` to `freed_slides`? Also, I noticed that the PDF's metadata says that it was created on 2023-02-08 21:16:54Z... Is it useful to mention that anywhere?